# C#: Reading a special formatted CSV

Tags: c#, algorithm, csv, data-extraction

My problem is that my csv file has data stored in form of a json file. I now need to extract that data in the most efficient way to create objects that store the data.

My csv-file looks like this:

```csv
1. 2022-09-19,"{
2.   "timestamp": 41202503,
3.   "machineId": 3567,
4.   "status": 16,
5.   "isActive": false,
6.   "scanWidth": 5.0,
7. }"
8. 2022-09-19,"{
9.   "timestamp": 41202505,
10.  "machineId": 3568,
11.   "status": 5,
12.   "isActive": true,
13.   "scanWidth": 1.4,
14. }"
15. 2022-09-19,"{
16.   "timestamp": 41202507,
17.   "machineId": 3569,
18.   "status": 12,
19.   "isActive": false,
20.   "scanWidth": 6.2,
21. }"
```

In my project I would have class called "MachineData" with all the relevant properties.
My question is now, how can I extract the data stored in this csv file?

Thanks again for helping!

Comment: Parse it as CSV, getting two colums, then parse the second column as json. Edit: I didn't think of the quotes, so this won't work. This is a very unusual format.

Comment: You will have to roll your own code to parse this. It doesn't look like a format a typical CSV parser could understand (arguably it *isn't* CSV at all).  The multiple lines in a cell are OK, because the cell is in quotes. While CSV allows for embedded quotes, they must be escaped by doubling them.

Comment: This isn't a CSV file. Don't call it one. This is a custom format. Treat it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a type to represent this data:

```cs
class ResultItem
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string MachineId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string IsActive { get; set; }
    public string ScanWidth { get; set; }
}
```

Use `Regex` and `Newtonsoft.Json` to extract the data:

```cs
//Remove the line number
csvText = Regex.Replace(csvText, @"\d+\. ", "");

//Match items with separating the date and the json in different groups
var matches = Regex.Matches(csvText, @"(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}),""(?<json>(.+\n){6}})", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Multiline);

var results = new List<ResultItem>();
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    //Getting values from json group
    var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultItem>(match.Groups["json"].Value);
    //Getting value from date group
    item.Date = match.Groups["date"].Value;
    results.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't normally recommend parsing json with Regular Expressions, but this is a special case, so here is a solution entirely based on RegEx:

```cs
string pattern = @"(?<date>[0-9-]+),""{\s+""timestamp"":\s+(?<timestamp>[0-9]+),\s+""machineId"":\s+(?<machineId>[0-9]+),\s+""status"":\s+(?<status>[0-9]+),\s+""isActive"":\s+(?<isActive>(true|false)),\s+""scanWidth"":\s+(?<scanWidth>[0-9\.]+),\s+}""";  
Regex rg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);  
  
foreach (Match match in rg.Matches(File.ReadAlltext("nameoffile.csv")))  
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["date"].Value); 
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["timestamp"].Value); 
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["machineId"].Value); 
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["status"].Value); 
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["isActive"].Value); 
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["scanWidth"].Value); 
}
```

Note that if the input differs the slightest this will fail (negative values, additional or missing white space, etc.).

**EDIT**
If the line numbers are part of the input, you need to add `[0-9]+\.\s+` in the beginning of the Regex to swallow the line number, the dot, and the white space, giving:

```cs
string pattern = @"[0-9]+\.\s+(?<date>[0-9-]+),""{\s+""timestamp"":\s+(?<timestamp>[0-9]+),\s+""machineId"":\s+(?<machineId>[0-9]+),\s+""status"":\s+(?<status>[0-9]+),\s+""isActive"":\s+(?<isActive>(true|false)),\s+""scanWidth"":\s+(?<scanWidth>[0-9\.]+),\s+}""";
```

Comment: Given the input from the OP it doesn't work. I don't think you accounted for the line numbers.

Comment: No, I did not. I assumed they weren't part of the input. If they are, the format is even more  odd than my first impression.